# Android: getTabHost() Error

Tags: android, android-layout

Im new to Android and Java development and am following the Tab Layout tutorial on the Android Dev site. Ive run into a problem with the code. Just using some copy-pasta magic to make sure I have no misspellings, Ive inserted all the needed code for the tutorial. Problem is that the getTabHost() is undefined... Here is the code:

```
public class AHActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, EvoActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("evolution").setIndicator("Evolution")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, physActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("physics").setIndicator("Physics")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your activity should extend TabActivity not Activity.

```
public class AHActivity extends TabActivity {
```

Note: Tabactivitity deprecated in latest versions, consider learning [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: Ok, So I updated that, somehow missed it in the tutorial, but get a bunch of deprecation warnings. Should I be getting these warnings? And I can launch the app to my 3.2.1 device but it crashes, and dont know how to find out the cause....
EDIT: I may know the cause, it could either be my sdk wasnt up to date, or because I didnt add the information for the activities to the manifest. I cant find out since Im now updating the sdk, which I should have done first, its been about 6 months...

Comment: As I said, it is deprecated, so warnings are legal there. If you are deploying on device by connecting to your development system you will see error messages in logcat.

Comment: Oh, WOW, Im out of it today. Sorry about that. Im going to go ahead and look into fragments and also check my logcat while running the program. Thanks, If I have any more questions, Ill reply to this post.